# shadow dom script to watch for changes in host

Tags: javascript, css, html, web-component, shadow-dom

I am creating an app where I need to manage a collection of elements that take advantage of the shadow dom. Since the template tag encapsulates content, I can keep the style and script with the elements in order for them to act on events. What I would like to know is if it is possible for script inside the shadowRoot to observe changes to properties of the host.

My proposed path is to attach a data attribute to the host and have shadow script listen for changes to it and then update elements inside the shadowRoot. I am aware that it is possible to use javascript to access elements in the shadowRoot and change them, but my desire is to experiment in modularization and reusability. I ultimately would like for this component to be reusable and react to changes in the hosts attributes.

Comment: I am fairly new to web component. Do we need have the complete code in the markup or can be lazy loaded when the page loads, like an iframe? If the code is locally available in the markup, it should be allowed. However if its shared utility lazy loaded over the web from a different domain, it might not be allowed. How about a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) to play around?

Comment: I have the basic idea in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rkichenama/Vg4gG/3/). I want to add a a script to the template that will watch for changes to the fill attribute of the host and then, in this example, change the font color inside the shadowRoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and figured I would share. It is likely not yet compatible with all browsers, but such is life.

In my script, I have a iffe/monad that processes my custom html tags, creating shadow roots and clones of a template as content. One of the arguments for the monad is the array of nodes that match my custom tag. While looping over them, I create a MutationObserver to watch for a particular attribute change in order to use the created shadow root in a closure.

```
            (function (tags, template) {
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(hexagons, function (v, k) {
                    var shadow = v.createShadowRoot();
                    shadow.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));

                    /* mutation observer */
                    var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
                            mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
                                shadow.querySelector('.seconds')
                                   .innerText(
                                      mutation.target.getAttribute(mutation.attributeName)
                                   )
                            });
                        });
                    observer.observe(v, { attributes: true, attributeFilter: ['bgcolor'] });
                }
            );
        }(document.querySelectorAll('time'), document.querySelector('template#time')));
```

The above works in Chrome and Firefox latest. I will keep looking for mroe browser friendly solutions.